# Core Data Model Url is Nil in Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using Apple Documented Code to link up CoreData xcdatamodeld file but it works brilliantly in the project but fails in Framework.
Here is the code I am using to create the managedObjectModel. **I get nil modelURL in case of Framework.**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [paths lastObject];

    self.persistantStorePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@.sqlite",name]];
    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.persistantStorePath];
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:name withExtension:@"momd"];

    self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    self.managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
```

Also, I tried [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] and the surprising point is, it works too.

I don't know why the Apple Documentation fails in case of Framework

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your model file is stored inside the framework bundle.

Calling `[NSBundle mainBundle]` will return the app bundle and not the framework bundle.

Try using `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[AClassInYourFramework class]]` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Alternative is to use framework package name to get the bundle